# Relative of a Glue

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> If zero plus six is a relative of a glue
>
> and four plus two is one who rides around
>
> and two plus two (or four) can harm or heal you,
>
> then what plus what equals a chemical compound?

Looking for the final answer in the form of “A number + A number = A word"

---

Hint:

> (7),(6),(?),(?)

Comment: I've not solved the puzzle so I might be wrong, but I suspect that what we are looking for isn't an *equation* but an *equality*. An additive equality could be , e.g., "7+2=9" while an equation is (roughly speaking) an equality with one or more unknown values, e.g. "3x+2y=12".

Comment: @Evargalo Yes, you’re right. I’m looking for the final, fully solved answer in the form of “A number + A number = A word (that is a chemical compound)". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Should this have the knowledge tag or is it trivial?

Comment: @Prim3numbah In my opinion, you don't need anything more than common knowledges to arrive at the answer. Everyone knows what the first word is and how it can be described as I did, and the same goes for the second word. The third word may require slightly less common knowledge, but it's not uncommon enough that I sincerely believe that if you solve the first two words and understand the core mechanics of the puzzle, you'll have an inkling of what the third word may be. The fourth word is a very common chemical compound.

Comment: Just a thought: I'm not sure how helpful the current hints are, since I would mainly use those for verifying an answer but they don't really reveal anything about the rule behind it; if I were to by chance figure out the final solution, it would just be another example of your rule that I couldn't figure out

Comment: @samm82 In this puzzle, it’s possible that if you think you found the words from any line that might fit their respective descriptions, you would then look at the num. + num. part and instantly realise what that rule may be about (An observant child might be able to point out what the rule is if they were given some or all of the words). The hint nudges you toward solving it from that angle and could verify that you are on the right track with that word. You can then use that same line of thinking to solve the other lines and finally confirm that the rule you suspected is right.

Comment: @samm82 I realised that a better approach would have been to give hints that directly pointed solvers towards the line of reasoning discussed here, rather than only listing letter counts without any meaningful context, or made these facts more obvious in the first place. Thank you for the constructive feedback! I'm trying to improve at designing puzzles, and I'll keep this in mind for when I have to add more hints to this puzzle or for when I’m making more puzzles in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe...

> **four plus zero** equals a chemical compound.

Because this puzzle is all about...

> **compound words** made from the names of two animals, based off the **number of legs** these creatures have.

In the examples:

> *If zero plus six is a relative of a glue*
>
>  This is SEAL (0 legs - its limbs are technically flippers) + ANT (6 legs) = **[SEALANT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealant)**
>
>  *and four plus two is one who rides around*
>
>  COW (4 legs) + BOY (2 legs) = **COWBOY** (If the enumeration of 6 letters was not already provided in a hint, I could have argued this to be HORSE+MAN as well...)
>
>  *and two plus two (or four) can harm or heal you,*
>
>  MAN (2 legs) + DRAKE (2 or 4 legs) = **MANDRAKE**. This one takes a little explaining - a drake can be a male duck (2 legs) or a type of [dragon](https://www.blackdrago.com/types/drake.htm) (4 legs). A [mandrake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrake) is a plant root that has historically been used as an anaesthetic but is also highly toxic when consumed in the wrong amounts.

So, the missing answer...

*then what plus what equals a chemical compound?*

> This is OX (4 legs) + IDE (0 legs) = **[OXIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxide)**, where an '[ide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ide_(fish))' is a freshwater fish, also known as an 'orfe'.

Comment: Yep, you've got it. Well done!